# Backwards compatible URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I've migrated from an old site onto Laravel and would like to support some of the old URLs in the new system. I used to have URLs like:

`old.site.com/page.php`

but this approach doesn't seem to work. Thoughts?

`Route::get('/page.php', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: You should just redirect your old paths with `.php` to the new site without the `.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your web server is probably catching that request and trying to send it to a .php file, so you probably will have to deal with your. So you probably will have to deal with rewriters and/or remap. So you'll, probably, have to do some rewritings like this:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/foo\.php$  /foo [PT]
```

Here's a documento to help with this, if you are using Apache 2 as web server: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html.